# Can't create a bootable ubuntu USB stick with ubuntu

Tags: 13.10, live-usb, startup-disk-creator

The startup disk creator crashes!

I followed the instructions carefully and I've tried many times (about 5 times). It crashes at the same part every time. When it asks for the password and says that it's installing the bootloader. I'm trying to make a ubuntu 13.10 live usb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try some alternative program to this preinstalled in Ubuntu like:

[UNetBootIn](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unetbootin/)
 - you can install him straight from this link,

or Live Usb Install from [here](http://live.learnfree.eu/).

Comment: alright! UNetBootIn is similar to that I used in windows and has good reviews! just what I wished for. thanks :D

Comment: just noticed that it doesn't have an option for ubuntu 13.10. Now what?

Comment: As I see on UNetBootIn website they don't support 13.10 yet, but you can use the second option of the app. Just download .iso image of cd from [ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) and load to the program by that option - Diskimage.

Comment: oooooh!! so that's the thing! okay thanks you so much :D

Answer (score 1):

4 easy steps to follow:

1) Download YUMI – Multiboot USB Creator from [here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/YUMI/ubuntu/yumi_0.0.1-1_all.deb)

2) Download ubuntu 13.10 from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?distro=desktop&bits=64&release=latest)

```
 (and please do follow this step as the reason for the crash may be a corrupt file)
```

3)click on YUMI and select your drive for the USB,select ubuntu as the distribution file and browse the iso file

[image]

4)Click create and you are good to go..!!

Comment: yes but this program only works for windows. in fact I thought of using it. This is how I installed ubuntu in the first place but I wanted a linux program. thanks :)

Comment: happy to see your problem solved..cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me and I had to force close the process although the USB did work as bootable anyway even though the process appeared unfinished. Although I would exercise caution and run it before installing from it, if that is your intention, in case there is any data loss.

I believe its a problem with Startup Disk Creator so installing a different tool for doing so should work fine.

Comment: I tried booting from the usb after the program had crashed but it wasn't recognized as bootable. anyways yes, most probably it's a problem with the program so I'll use another :)

Answer (score 0):

Install squashfs-tools

```
sudo apt-get install squashfs-tools
```

and then use unetbootin. Started having this problem with every usb i tried to make until i realized that squashfs-tools was not being installed.
While Multiboot is a great tool, if you notice when it gets installed, squashfs-tools does as well.