# Installing Ubuntu over Windows 7

Tags: system-installation

I'm thinking about replacing my actual OS (Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit) with the latest version of Ubuntu, but i'm totally new with this "switching OS" thing. What steps should i follow to correctly replace Windows with Ubuntu? I'm using a Samsung laptop, model 305V5A S02.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely become familiar with the use of terminal and the work environment before switching from Ubuntu.If you are ready with that part and are new on switching OS (operating system,not SO) you can follow these steps :

1) Make a bootable USB or CD,this may help
[create a bootable ubuntu USB stick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/386108/cant-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-stick-with-ubuntu/386183#386183)

2)Run the setup, in which [How to replace Windows with Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/331360/220995) may help.

And dont forget to **take a backup of all important data**.

Comment: Ops, sorry!I'm italian and in our language it's "Sistema Operativo"..!

Comment: oh...nessun problema :P

Comment: Deformazione professionale :D

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use virtual machine like `vmware` and install `ubuntu` and learn the commands if you are new to linux because it is difficult for first time users.

but if you have no difficulty using ubuntu , just go to ubuntu official website and download the `iso file` and put it in a cd using `poweriso` and `boot` the computer with that cd.

all other doubts will be cleared by google.

Comment: I already use Ubuntu on vmware yes, i'm not new to the Ubuntu/Linux world. It is really that simple? There aren't any others preliminary checks to do?

Comment: then try the second paragraph and lets go