# Failure to install ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64

Tags: installation, wubi

below error is the one am getting on installation failure

```
12-07 01:25 ERROR  TaskList: [Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (2, 'getaddrinfo failed')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\downloader.py", line 77, in download
  File "\lib\urlgrabber\grabber.py", line 927, in urlgrab
  File "\lib\urlgrabber\grabber.py", line 845, in _retry
  File "\lib\urlgrabber\grabber.py", line 913, in retryfunc
  File "\lib\urlgrabber\grabber.py", line 1001, in __init__
  File "\lib\urlgrabber\grabber.py", line 1072, in _do_open
  File "\lib\urlgrabber\grabber.py", line 1188, in _make_request
URLGrabError: [Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (2, 'getaddrinfo failed')>
12-07 01:25 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
12-07 01:25 ERROR  root: [Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (2, 'getaddrinfo failed')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 132, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\downloader.py", line 77, in download
  File "\lib\urlgrabber\grabber.py", line 927, in urlgrab
  File "\lib\urlgrabber\grabber.py", line 845, in _retry
  File "\lib\urlgrabber\grabber.py", line 913, in retryfunc
  File "\lib\urlgrabber\grabber.py", line 1001, in __init__
  File "\lib\urlgrabber\grabber.py", line 1072, in _do_open
  File "\lib\urlgrabber\grabber.py", line 1188, in _make_request
URLGrabError: [Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (2, 'getaddrinfo failed')>
12-07 01:25 ERROR  root: Could not remove: C:\ubuntu\install\ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 426, in download_iso
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'C:\\ubuntu\\install\\ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso'
12-07 01:25 DEBUG  TaskList: New task download
12-07 01:25 ERROR  root: Could not remove: C:\ubuntu\install\ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 426, in download_iso
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'C:\\ubuntu\\install\\ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso'
12-07 01:25 DEBUG  TaskList: New task download
12-07 01:25 ERROR  root: Could not remove: C:\ubuntu\install\ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 426, in download_iso
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'C:\\ubuntu\\install\\ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso'
12-07 01:25 DEBUG  TaskList: New task download
12-07 01:25 ERROR  TaskList: Could not retrieve the required installation files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 600, in get_iso
Exception: Could not retrieve the required installation files
12-07 01:25 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
12-07 01:25 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
```

Comment: Are you installing Ubuntu 13.10 using Wubi (in Windows)?

Comment: maybe this could help..

[Installing Ubuntu 13.10][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/386457/installing-ubuntu-over-windows-7/386472#386472

Answer (score -1):

If you are installing 13.10 using Wubi then that is likely your issue. Wubi is not supported in 13.10 you will need to follow the official install instructions which can be found here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest

Comment: So how to install 13.10 then ?

Comment: Do I need to restart laptop and select boot from CD/DVD like that ?

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest Here are the official install documents

Comment: Wubi is still supported. If you read [this ancient meta post](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6509/449) you're using old data. I've just updated it. Also [see this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7596/449)... That said, a proper dual boot *is* a better install.